# Theorem dual to trivial kernel $\iff$ injective in $\boldsymbol{Grp}$

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, duality-theorems

Cokernels are "dual" to kernels. I've been told that if X dual to Y and there's a theorem about X then there's a "dual" theorem about Y.

Theorem: In $\boldsymbol{Grp}$ a homomorphism has trivial kernel iff it is injective.

However it is not true that a group homomorphism has trivial cokernel iff it's surjective. So what would instead be the dual theorem to the above theorem? (or have I been lied to and those dual theorems don't always exist?)

Comment: Cokernels in $\mathrm{Grp}$ are not really cokernels in the strict sense: they do not fulfill the universal property of cokernels, which the failure of your dualization is a witness of. If you work in an Abelian category (such as the category of _Abelian_ groups) instead, this dualization works, and your proposition is true.

Comment: @BenSteffan book i'm reading claims that there are non-surjective group homomorphisms with trivial cokernel. They give as an example the inclusion map of the subgroup <(12)> of $S_3$

Comment: I realized that your definition defines the cokernel of a map as the quotient by the _normal closure_ of its image, not as the quotient by the image itself (which is only a group if the image is normal), which is why I was confused.

Comment: The dual theorem of course exists. But it applies to the opposite category $\mathbf{Grp}^{op}$, which is not equivalent to $\mathbf{Grp}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dual theorem holds in the opposite category $\boldsymbol{Grp}^{op}$, which is not equivalent to $\boldsymbol{Grp}$.

This sort of duality holds in general when a theorem is true for all categories, or at least some subset of categories that are self dual. If for all categories $\mathcal C$, some theorem holds for $\mathcal C$, then the dual theorem holds for $\mathcal C^{op}$. Since the original theorem also holds for the category $\mathcal C^{op}$, the dual theorem holds for $\mathcal (C^{op})^{op} = \mathcal C$.

This particular theorem [doesn't hold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2312656/if-the-kernel-cokernel-of-a-morphism-f-is-trivial-then-is-f-injective-su?rq=1) for all categories (where kernels, cokernels, injectivity and surjectivity can be defined). Thus, the dual theorem is not guaranteed to hold.

---

Comment: How does that category look like? Is there an easy description for it?

Comment: That might warrant another question along the lines of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/980933/what-is-the-opposite-category-of-set) or [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29442/what-is-the-opposite-category-of-the-category-of-modules-or-hopf-algebra-repres?rq=1). If pressed, I'd use the answer to that first question to say that $\boldsymbol {Grp}^{op}$ is the category of cogroup objects in the category of complete atomic boolean algebras.